# Why is ENTER needed when executing reverse search from Vim command line?

Tags: vim, command-line-arguments

I'm trying to run `vim` on a file and execute a search command to take me to the correct location.

When I use:

```
vi myfile.py -c /print
```

it correctly takes the cursor to the line<sup>(a)</sup> with the first occurrence.

However, when I use the search-backwards option:

```
vi myfile.py -c ?print
```

it seems to require me to hit <kbd>ENTER</kbd> before continuing:

```
"myfile.py" 470L, 19634C
Press ENTER or type command to continue
```

After I hit <kbd>ENTER</kbd>, it is on the last line containing the text as expected, I'm just not sure *why* I have to hit <kbd>ENTER</kbd> first.

Is there a way to do this and be immediately at the correct text?

---

<sup>(a)</sup> This is *another* mystery. If I search within Vim, the cursor is at the correct location on the line rather than on the first non-whitespace character. I *think* that's because they're being treated as `ex` commands rather than `vi` commands (so `:/print` rather than `/print`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"search hit TOP, continuing at BOTTOM" will show up whenever your search wraps around the document, unless you have `s` in your `shortmess` (`:help 'shortmess'`). This will always happen if you search backwards from the first line, but would not happen if you were to search forward.

There might be some other messages too; check `:messages` to see what's everything that popped up. The "Press ENTER or type command to continue" (`:help hit-enter`) shows up when you can't fit all the messages on the command line height (`:help 'cmdheight'`) and Vim is afraid you'll miss something.

I believe when you search backwards, Vim is displaying your filename, and then the search wraparound prompt; and your `cmdheight` is set to `1`.

You can try to avoid it by either `set cmdheight=2` (make room for both messages), or by `set shortmess+=s` (don't display the search wraparound message) in your vimrc. A third way would be explicitly preventing the search wraparound message just in this case, as opposed to setting a global option (`:help :silent`): `vim myfile.py -c "silent ?print"`

---

You are correct that `-c` is executing an ex command; `-c /print` is actually doing `:/print`, not `/print` (`:help :/`), which is why you land on start of the line, and not on a match.

You can work around it by explicitly using the normal mode search (`help :normal`). Note that every command passed to `:normal` must be complete, or it will be cancelled, so we need to include the final Enter key as well:

```
vim myfile.py +"norm /print^M"
```

where `^M` is <kbd>Ctrl-V</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd> (I'm also using `+` as a shorter equivalent of `-c` command line option: `:help +cmd`.) If you have to script it, and thus inserting a literal `^M` is not really nice, you can also use this (`:help :execute`) to be able to use the Vim's key name (`:help key-notation`):

```
vim myfile.py +'exe "norm /print\<cr>"'
```

---

Together with the previous issue about Enter, you can use the following combined command to search for last `print`, landing directly on it, and not having to press Enter. It's a bit of a monster, so you may want to make a bash function, or even a Vim function, if you will want to use it often:

```
vim myfile.py +'exe "sil norm ?print\<cr>"'
```

Here it is as a Vim function you can just plop into your vimrc:

```
function! g:norm_silently(what)
  exe "sil norm " . a:what . "\<cr>"
endfunction
command! -nargs=1 F call g:norm_silently(<q-args>)
```

which you can then use as:

```
vim myfile.py +'F ?print'
```

Comment: My attempt to remove the `:silent` and need to escape `<cr>` key: `vim myfile.py +'$+?print?norm gnov`

Answer (score 0):

After more investigation, it looks like footnote `(a)` in the question holds the key. These *are* indeed `ex`-style commands which is why they go to the start of the line. That's evidenced by the fact that `$` goes to the last line, *not* `G`.

In addition, it looks like any command that actually has to wrap will cause the behaviour of needing the <kbd>ENTER</kbd> key. This includes (as the question does) searching backward from the first line or (on further testing) searching forward from the last:

```
vim myfile.py -c \$ -c /print
```

And *that* is the actual solution. Provided the last line is not the one holding the string you're looking for, using `$` to go to the last line and then searching backward with `?print` will put you on the last line with that string, without having to press <kbd>ENTER</kbd>.